# Разбираю JSON строку и в месте пустого массива получаю No value for []

Tags: java, android, json

Проблема в следующем у меня есть json строка которую я получаю с сервера она может содержать или не содержать различные поля, поля вроде как пофиксил а вот с jsonarray проблема не могу понять он нулевой и постоянно бросает exception

```
 try {
        JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(result);
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jObject = jsonarray.optJSONObject(i);
            User user = new User();
            user.setId(jObject.getString("id"));
            user.setEmail(jObject.getString("email"));
            user.setNick(jObject.getString("nick"));
            user.setSex(jObject.getInt("sex"));
            user.setBio(jObject.getString("bio"));
            user.setCntPhone(jObject.getString("cntPhone"));
            user.setCntWWW(jObject.getString("cntWWW"));
            user.setLocCountry(jObject.getString("locCountry"));
            user.setLocCity(jObject.getInt("locCity"));
            if (jObject.has("avatar")) {
                JSONObject objAvatar = new JSONObject(jObject.optString("avatar"));
                user.setAvatar(objAvatar.optString("original"));
                user.setThumbAvatar(objAvatar.optString("thumb"));
            }
            JSONObject objCountry = new JSONObject(jObject.optString("country"));
            user.setCoutryName(objCountry.optString("native_name"));
            JSONObject objCity = new JSONObject(jObject.optString("city"));
            user.setCityName(objCity.optString("name"));
            JSONObject jsonIterests = new JSONObject(jObject.getString("interests"));
            JSONArray jsonArrayInterests = jsonIterests.getJSONArray("data");
            List<String> interests = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int j = 0; j < jsonArrayInterests.length(); j++) {
                interests.add((String) jsonArrayInterests.get(j));
            }
            user.setInterests(interests);
            if (jObject.has("vehicles")) {
                JSONArray jsonArrayVehicles = jObject.getJSONArray(jObject.optString("vehicles"));
                if (jsonArrayVehicles.isNull(0)) {
                    List<Vehicles> vehiclesList = new ArrayList<>();
                    Vehicles vehicles = new Vehicles();
                    vehicles.setId("");
                    vehicles.setUuid("");
                    vehicles.setFirm(0);
                    vehicles.setModel(0);
                    vehicles.setYear(0);
                    user.setVehicles(vehiclesList);
                } else {
                    List<Vehicles> vehiclesList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (int k = 0; k < jsonArrayVehicles.length(); k++) {
                        JSONObject json = jsonArrayVehicles.optJSONObject(k);
                        Vehicles vehicles = new Vehicles();
                        vehicles.setId(json.getString("id"));
                        vehicles.setUuid(json.getString("uuid"));
                        vehicles.setFirm(json.getInt("firm"));
                        vehicles.setModel(json.getInt("model"));
                        vehicles.setYear(json.getInt("year"));
                    }
                    user.setVehicles(vehiclesList);
                }
            }
            userList.add(user);
```

Вот json часть строки в которой ошибка.

```
[
    {
        "id": "7536f9d0-eed3-11e5-b13a-11cc9bb4a464",
        "email": "johnyzzzzz@mail.ru",
        "nick": "johnyzzzzzz",
        "sex": "1",
        "interests": "{\"data\":[\"Скорость\",\"Тюнинг\",\"DIY (Гараж)\",\"Стант\"]}",
        "bio": "ncoeowjfjhr",
        "cntPhone": "64646852",
        "cntWWW": "jwifofowofjr",
        "locLat": "0.0000000",
        "locLng": "0.0000000",
        "locCountry": "MD",
        "locCity": "617830",
        "country": {
            "code": "MD",
            "name": "Moldova",
            "native_name": "Молдавия"
        },
        "city": {
            "id": "617830",
            "name": "Maiac",
            "alternate_names": "Maiac,Majak,Mayak,Маяк",
            "lat": "47.2372700",
            "lng": "29.3849800",
            "country_code": "MD",
            "timezone": "Europe/Chisinau"
        },
        "vehicles": []
    },
```

Comment: 1. Приложите стек исключения. 2. Приводите только проблемный код, например строка с ошибкой

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всем спасибо кто уделил время и посмотрел, решил самостоятельно проблему, возможно кому пригодиться.
Проблема оказалась в следующем: в этой строке

```
JSONArray jsonArrayVehicles = jObject.getJSONArray(jObject.optString("vehicles"));
```

у меня выдавало исключение. Оказалось все слишком просто `getJSONArray` необходимо заменить на `optJSONArray`. Тогда если массив нулевой с ним можно работать, в противном случае исключение.